# Vue Directive on Laravel Collective Html Form

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How do I use a vue.js directive on a form object created using laravel collectives library.

ex: `{{Form::open(['route' => 'route.name'])}}`

How would I add v-mydirective to the `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extra attributes to the array

```
{{Form::open([
  'route' => 'route.name',
  'v-if' => 'foo'
])}}
```

Comment: right, but I don't want v-if="foo" , I want just v-mydirective.

Comment: have you tried `'v-mydirective' => true` or anything similar?

Comment: I have not trued that